# Xcode 7.0 beta 6でSwift版のGameテンプレートプロジェクト(OpenGL ES)がiPhone5以下でうまく動かない

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, opengl, debugging

こんばんは。毎度お世話になっております。
Xcode 7.0 beta 6とSwift 2を使用してiOS開発を行っている者です。

Xcode付属のGameテンプレートのOpenGL ESを使ったサンプルプロジェクト（青い立方体と赤い立方体が回るプログラム）が、
iPhone 5以下(iOS 8.4)のシュミレータ上でうまく動作しない
（実行はできるが描画がおかしくなる。特にランタイムエラーなどは起こっていない）のですが、
正常に動作させるにはどのような修正を施せば良いでしょうか

ちなみに、Objective-C版や、Swift版のiPhone 5s以上のシュミレータでは正常に動作することを確認しています。